# Is Chain Lightning considered a ray spell?

Tags: spells, monsters, pathfinder-2e

Is Chain Lightning considered a ray-typed spell?

I couldn't find an official definition for rays (unlike lines and cones), but it seems to be a "type" of spell because it's referenced by this monster ability:

> **Carapace** Tarrasque is immune to cones, lines, rays, and magic missile spells. These effects bounce harmlessly off its scales.

Comment: Answered the question, but it would help to know why you're asking. I'm assuming you're expecting there to be a mechanical distinction based on whether it's a ray or not, and knowing what you expect to change based on its ray-ness would be useful.

Comment: There's an end-game/high-level monster whose stat block states that it is "immune to rays." Originally I included that reference as part of the question, but I got down-voted.

So I rewrote the question without mentioning it, thinking that maybe the person didn't appreciate the spoiler or meta gaming.

Comment: The downvotes were uncalled for as this is a legitimate question. I added the monster ability to the question, with spoilers just to be safe.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding.  "cones, lines, rays, and magic missile spells." should be parsed as "cones", "lines", "rays", and "magic missile spells".  The Tarrasque cannot be hurt by cones, such as traffic cones, lines, such as cocaine, rays (the fish), nor magic missile spells.  All of them bounce harmlessly off its scales.  To harm a Tarrasque with fish, you need to use either piranhas, gold ones, or sharks.  This is clear as "ray" is not a spell keyword, and by placing it as the penultimate spot you have to reinterpret the clause!

Comment: You can pretty safely post any stats and abilites of creatures that aren't part of a pre-written adventure. The Tarrasque is just a monster that appears in the Bestiary, not the last boss of Age of Ashes. So it's fine. The downvotes were probably people thinking you hadn't bothered to read the relevant rules (jokes on them, they don't exist in Pathfinder 2e yet)

Answer (score 9):

### "Ray" is not a defined type of spell.

There are two ways that a spell affects a subject, either with an area or a target (from [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=286)):

> Sometimes a spell has an area, which can be a burst, cone, emanation, or line. [...]

> Some spells allow you to directly target a creature, an object, or something that fits a more specific category. [...]

"Ray" isn't defined as a selection mode for a spell, nor is it defined elsewhere, including in notable rays like [Scorching Ray](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=992) or [Ray of Enfeeblement](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=244). It is [not a trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx) and with no other rules that affect rays (e.g. there's no equivalent to [1e Weapon Focus specifically calling out rays](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Weapon%20Focus)), there's no specific in-game classification for a spell being a ray or not.

As of 2023-03-09 all published spells with "ray" in their names include a ranged spell attack, but not all ranged spell attacks count as rays (e.g. [Hydraulic Push](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=154)). [Searing Light](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=269) says it's a ray in the description, but not the name. Short of just basing it on a heuristic like "does the name contain 'ray'" or "does the description contain 'ray'," there's no specific category for a ray.

### Chain Lightning is just a targeted spell.

Even if rays *were* a defined type of spell or trait, [Chain Lightning](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=33) doesn't mention rays at all; it is a targeted (i.e. non-area) spell. Unless you define "ray" as broadly as "anything that targets and would have something moving along an arc" (to exclude things like Finger of Death), I wouldn't consider Chain Lightning to be a ray.

Comment: I think I figured it out, feel free to add to your answer. After looking at 4-5 different spells with 'ray' in their name, it turns out that all of them require a ranged spell attack. In other words, 'rays' means spells that make ranged spell attacks.

Comment: @Khashir Spells with "ray" in their name (at least the currently published ones that I've seen) require ranged spell attacks, but not all ranged spell attacks are rays. [Hydraulic Push](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=154) or [Searing Light](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=269) are examples of ranged spell attacks without "ray" in their names (although Searing Light does say it's a ray in the description) and some other spells like Produce Flame or Aqueous Blast involve ranged spell attacks and also aren't rays.

Answer (score 2):

Ray is not a type of spell in Pathfinder 2e. Chain Lightning targets a number of creatures within range, and so does not qualify as an area-of-effect for any metamagic effects or similar rules text.